# Working on downloaded/fetched SQLite database file without saving it in local storage

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to download SQLite database file from a URL and run query on it to read data and store it in another already existing SQLite database? Or I need to save it locally and do the operation thereafter?

Comment: What's the difference between "downloading" and "saving locally"?

Comment: oops! Wrong question, SORRY! (sleepless hours)
@cricket_007

Comment: Well, my point is that you can't run a query over a sqlite file that isn't on the local disk. If you needed to do that, you're probably looking for a MySql server instead, for example

Comment: yeah, started thinking over it, but I would possibly go with database file as it would save some unnecessary bandwidth. and Thank you for reminding me about the difference. :p @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about querying a sqlite table immediately after downloading it. However, I have a similar experience of downloading a sqlite table from internet and saving it locally in the `databases` directory. Then I could run the query in that table just after saving it.

I am sharing the code for saving the table in the `databases` directory.

```
public static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + "com.example.yourapppackagename" + "/databases/";

try {
    inputStreamDownloaded = downloadFileAndReturnInputStream();

    File dir = new File(DataHelper.DB_PATH);
    if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir();
    File f = new File(DB_PATH + "downloaded_table.sqlite");
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.createNewFile();
    }

    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = inputStreamDownloaded.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    inputStreamDownloaded.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Once the `.sqlite` file is saved locally, you can run query on `downloaded_table`. Hope that helps!